# Let $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ be a family of disjoint sets where $|A_i|=|A_j|\ge\aleph_0\space\forall i\in I$. Is $|\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i|=|A_i|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

> Let $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ be a family of sets where $|A_i|=|A_j|\ge\aleph_0$ and $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$.

I found that we can prove $|\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}A_i|=|A_i|$ for all $i\in I$ in case $I$ is countablle by induction. I have no idea in case $I$ is uncountable.

Comment: @ajotatxe I'm sorry. That's a typo. It should be $|X_i|$.

Comment: @ajotatxe It's my mistake a gain. It should be $A_i$.

Comment: @bof It's a typo. It should be $A_i$, not $X_i$.

Comment: Thanks @bof ! What if $|A_i|>\aleph_0$ for all $i\in I$ and $|I|>\aleph_0$?

Comment: We can use the axiom of choice, right? So if $A_i\ne\emptyset$ we have a function $f:I\to\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ with $f(i)\in A_i$, and $f$ is injective if $A_i\cap A_j\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @bof Yes we can.

Comment: So you get a counterexample whenever $|A_i|=\kappa$ for all $i\in I$ and $|I|\gt\kappa.$

Comment: Under the assumptions in your header (and assuming the axiom of choice), $$|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i|=|A_i\times I|=|A_i|\cdot|I|.$$

Comment: Thank you @bof !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Choice, just consider infinite sets $A$ and $I$. Let $A_i=\{i\}\times A$, for every $i\in I$. Then
$$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=I\times A$$
and then
$$\left|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right|=|I|\cdot |A|=\max\{|I|,|A|\}$$

Comment: Did you mean $|\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i|$ rather than $\bigcup_{i\in I}|A_i|$?